# Custom drop down menu in responsive navigation

Tags: magento2, menu

We utilized a XML snippet in order to load a specific block into the Topnavi.

Now, when in responsive mode we are having all topmenu items as a normal list in the menu.

Normal:
[image: Normal view]
Responsive view:
[image: Responsive view]

I do want to have "Sales Partners", "Electronic Components", ... in a specific Submenu, like I have it for the Menu items:

[image]

How can I do this? In my `default.xml` I have something like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
      <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="top-navigation">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">top-navigation</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

This loads the desired block which is a block due to the translation problems we have for multilingual pages.

This loads the block `top-navigation` which holds this content:

```
<ul class="header links show">
    <li class="nav item">
        <a href="/unternehmen"><span>&Uuml;ber uns</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <li class="view-company-element"><a href="/unternehmen/news">News</a></li>

            <li class="view-company-element"><a href="/rochester-electronics">Rochester Electronics</a></li>

            <li class="view-company-element"><a href="/osram-opto-semiconductors">OSRAM OS</a></li>

            <li class="view-company-element"><a href="/unternehmen/end-of-life-management">End-Of-Life Management</a></li>

            <li class="view-company-element"><a href="/unternehmen/zertifizierte-qualitaet">Zertifizierte Qualit&auml;t</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/customer/account/">Mein Konto</a></li>
    <li class="authorization-link" data-label="oder"><a href="/customer/account/login/">Anmelden</a></li>
    <li class="nav item"><a href="/checkout/cart/">Warenkorb</a></li>
    <li class="nav item"><a href="/contact/">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

What can I do in order to get this stuff working?

Comment: Could you please share your url? I need to check once.

Comment: No I cant, but I can add outputted HTML to the question itself. Just give me several minutes, and then I'll add it.

Comment: Please see my updated question @Tonmoy

Comment: Trying to debug how the product section comes with a drop down. I think you missed some classes. Try to find that I wish you can solve this problem.

Comment: Try this http://store.ibnab.com/free-magento-2-easy-megamenu.html

Answer (score -1):

Try to compare with the following code,

```
<li class="level0 nav-3 level-top parent ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a class="level-top ui-corner-all" href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men.html" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span><span>Men</span></a>
<ul class="level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display: none; top: 47px; left: 0px;" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
    <li class="level1 nav-3-1 first parent ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/tops-men.html" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-17" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span><span>Tops</span></a><ul class="level1 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all expanded" style="display: none; top: 36px; left: 0px;" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true"><li class="level2 nav-3-1-1 first ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html" id="ui-id-19" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Jackets</span></a></li><li class="level2 nav-3-1-2 ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/tops-men/hoodies-and-sweatshirts-men.html" id="ui-id-20" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Hoodies &amp; Sweatshirts</span></a></li><li class="level2 nav-3-1-3 ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/tops-men/tees-men.html" id="ui-id-21" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Tees</span></a></li><li class="level2 nav-3-1-4 last ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/tops-men/tanks-men.html" id="ui-id-22" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Tanks</span></a></li></ul></li><li class="level1 nav-3-2 last parent ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/bottoms-men.html" aria-haspopup="true" id="ui-id-18" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span><span>Bottoms</span></a><ul class="level1 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all expanded" style="display: none;" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false"><li class="level2 nav-3-2-1 first ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/bottoms-men/pants-men.html" id="ui-id-23" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Pants</span></a></li><li class="level2 nav-3-2-2 last ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/men/bottoms-men/shorts-men.html" id="ui-id-24" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span>Shorts</span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li>
```

Comment: I can change the classes, but this does not change the behaviour of the menu.

Comment: Do you have any way..I want to see the section live!

Comment: give me a shot when u are there.. dont wanna leave it public for so long.